# How to improve my pattern for regex parsing?

Tags: python, regex

I want to change the `pattern` so that it does not only match strings with both unit and amount but also unit alone. For instance, I want it to match "cubes" as well, even though it does not have an amount listed. Similarly, if the string just has the amount and not the unit, I want it to match the amount alone too. Currently, the output returned is

```
['1.0', '0.07', '32.0', '0.12', '1.01', 'cubes', '2']
```

I want the output to be as follows:

```
['1.0', '0.07', '32.0', '0.12', '1.01', '1.0', '2.0']
```

Here is the code:

```
list_of_texts = ["1oz", "2ml", "4cup", "1 wedge","2 slices", "cubes", "2"]

pattern = r"(^[\d -/]+)(oz|ml|cl|tsp|teaspoon|teaspoons|tea spoon|tbsp|tablespoon|tablespoons|table spoon|cup|cups|qt|quart|quarts|drop|drop|shot|shots|cube|cubes|dash|dashes|l|L|liters|Liters|wedge|wedges|pint|pints|slice|slices|twist of|top up|small bottle)"


new_list = []

for text in list_of_texts:
    re_result = re.search(pattern, text)

    if re_result:
        amount = re_result.group(1).strip()
        unit = re_result.group(2).strip()
        print(amount)
        print(unit)

        if "-" in amount:
            ranged = True
        else:
            ranged = False

        amount = re.sub(r"(\d) (/\d)",r"\1\2",amount) 
        amount = amount.replace("-","+").replace(" ","+").strip()
        amount = re.sub(r"[+]+","+",amount)
        amount_in_dec = frac_to_dec_converter(amount.split("+"))
        amount = np.sum(amount_in_dec)

        if ranged:
            to_oz = (amount*liquid_units[unit])/2
        else:
            to_oz = amount*liquid_units[unit]

        new_list.append(str(round(to_oz,2)))

    else:
        new_list.append(text)
```

Note: I have a dictionary that has conversion units

Comment: A regexp can't match something that isn't in the string. If the string is `cubes` it can't return `1.0`. You need to do that in your code, not the regexp.

Comment: `[ -/]` is the range of characters with ASCII codes 32 through 47. Is that your intent with that part of the regexp>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the number optional by using `*` instead of `+`. Then if the first capture group is empty, treat it as `1.0`.

```
pattern = r"(^[\d -/]*)(oz|ml|cl|tsp|teaspoon|teaspoons|tea spoon|tbsp|tablespoon|tablespoons|table spoon|cup|cups|qt|quart|quarts|drop|drop|shot|shots|cube|cubes|dash|dashes|l|L|liters|Liters|wedge|wedges|pint|pints|slice|slices|twist of|top up|small bottle)"

for text in list_of_texts:
    re_result = re.search(pattern, text)

    if re_result:
        amount = re_result.group(1).strip()
        if amount == '':
            amount = '1.0'
        unit = re_result.group(2).strip()
        print(amount)
        print(unit)

        # rest of your code
```

Comment: Hi, if I want the entries like ",orange" or "(if needed)" to not include "," or "(" as a part of the amount, how should I modify the code?

Comment: Add an optional pattern to the regexp that matches those things.